# Returning content which is a child node of JSON data

Tags: json, marketing-cloud

We have succesfully queries our clients site and are pulling JSON product data. However the product price is stored within a child node called media and we do not know how to extract it - we can extract fields from the parent node though. We need to pull out >>media>>price.

Successfully pulling data from parent node:

```
%%[ var @Json
set @Json = HTTPGet("https://www.ourwebiste/productid",false,0,@CallStatus) ]%%

{{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxRows = 20}}
     {{.data}}
    { "target" : "@Json" }
     {{/data}}
     Name: {{name}}
     productcode: {{baseProductCode}}
{{/datasource}}
```

Here is the JSON data

```
{"baseProductCode":"P52789915","displayColour":"#00AB84","name":"Men's 
Slip On Safety Shoe Burke - Black","description":"Men's slip on work shoe 
featuring a steel toe, a leather upper for durability and a technical 
cushioned insock to absorb shock when 
walking.","ratings":2.3333333333333335,"colourVariants":
[{"code":"52789915","name":"Men's Slip On Safety Shoe Burke - 
Black","sizeVariants":
[{"code":"52790010","name":"6","price":"$69","inStock":true},
{"code":"52790027","name":"7","price":"$69","inStock":true},
{"code":"52790034","name":"8","price":"$69","inStock":false},
{"code":"52790041","name":"9","price":"$69","inStock":true},
{"code":"52790058","name":"10","price":"$69","inStock":true},
{"code":"52790065","name":"11","price":"$69","inStock":true},
{"code":"52790072","name":"12","price":"$69","inStock":true}],"media":
[{"standard":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/medias/static_content/product/image
s/large/41/21/A814121.jpg","thumbnail":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/medias/st
atic_content/product/images/thumb/41/21/A814121.jpg"},
{"standard":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/medias/static_content/product/images
/large/41/27/A814127.jpg","thumbnail":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/medias/sta
tic_content/product/images/thumb/41/27/A814127.jpg"}],"price":"$69","inStoc
k":true}],"features":[{"name":"Materials and Composition","value":["Upper: 
Leather","Lining: Synthetic","Sole: Synthetic"]},{"name":"Product 
Features","value":["Leather upper","Steel toe","Technical cushioned insock 
to absorb shock when walking"]},{"name":"Care Instructions","value":
["Machine Washable"]}],"sizeChartUrl":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/size-
chart/menshoe","deliveryModes":[{"available":true,"description":"Free for 
orders over $19. Not available to all stores. Allow 4-10 business days 
before pickup.","name":"Click + Collect","excludesCountryStore":false},
{"available":true,"description":"Free for orders over $75 (excluding large 
items). Allow 3-10 business days for delivery.","name":"Home 
Delivery","excludesCountryStore":false},
{"available":false,"description":"For apparel only orders. Not available to 
all locations. Available for orders placed by 12pm Mon to 
Fri","name":"Express Delivery","excludesCountryStore":false}],"infoLinks":
[{"name":"FAQs","url":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/modal/faqs"},
{"name":"Payments
+ Delivery","url":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/modal/payment-delivery"},{"name":"Refunds
+ Returns","url":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/modal/refunds-returns"}],"code":"52790027"}
```

Anyone know how to extract the price from the media node?

Thanks for your help
Bryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I managed to work this out.  It doesn't look like there is a standard way of returning a sub object from the JSON data. After some research I found this way from another thread. Is there an easier way?

```
%%[ 
  var @Json2 
  set @Json2 = HTTPGet("https://mywebsite/productid",false,0,@CallStatus) 
]%%

{{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxRows = 20}}
  {{.data}}
  { "target" : "@Json2" }
  {{/data}}
  Name: {{name}}
  productcode: {{baseProductCode}}
{{/datasource}}

<script runat="server"> 

  Platform.Load("Core","1");

  function set(key, val) {   
    var newVal = val != null ? Stringify(val) : "{}";   
    Variable.SetValue(key, newVal); 
  }

  var Json=Variable.GetValue("@Json2");
  var _JsonObject = eval('(' + Json + ')');
  set("@colourVariants", _JsonObject.colourVariants); 

</script>

{{.dataobject ColorVar type=variable source=@colourVariants maxrows=20}}
  {{.data}} 
      {"target": "@colourVariants"} 
  {{/data}} 
{{/dataobject}} 

Here is the price: {{#ColorVar}} {{Price}} {{/ColorVar}}  {{/datasource}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to process this in Apex?

If so, dump it into JSON2Apex:

http://pastebin.com/vN64jFsP

Then pull out the fields you want from the class instances.

Price isn't in the media node. (Unless I failed at pasting). Media is just a url, which makes sense really.

Anyway. You can do this:

```
WebsiteJSON webjson = WebsiteJSON.parse('<your json>');
for (WebsiteJSON.ColourVariants cv : webjson.colourVariants) {
    System.debug('Name: '+cv.name+' Price: '+cv.price);
    for (WebsiteJSON.SizeVariants sv : cv.sizeVariants) {
        System.debug('----Name: '+sv.name+' Price: '+sv.price);
    }
}
```

Which gives this:

```
|DEBUG|Name: Men's Slip On Safety Shoe Burke - Black Price: $69
|DEBUG|----Name: 6 Price: $69
|DEBUG|----Name: 7 Price: $69
|DEBUG|----Name: 8 Price: $69
|DEBUG|----Name: 9 Price: $69
|DEBUG|----Name: 10 Price: $69
|DEBUG|----Name: 11 Price: $69
|DEBUG|----Name: 12 Price: $69
```

Comment: No I am trying to process this in SFMC (Exact Target) unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

As of the [January 2016 release](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/january_2016_release/#platform) there is a way to parse nested JSON data with GTL using the new "nested" datasource type.

Here is an example that pulls data from 3 different layers of the JSON structure:

```
%%[
var @Json2 set @Json2 = '{"baseProductCode":"P52789915","displayColour":"#00AB84","name":"Mens Slip On Safety Shoe Burke - Black","description":"Mens slip on work shoe  featuring a steel toe, a leather upper for durability and a technical cushioned insock to absorb shock when walking.","ratings":"2.33","colourVariants":[{"code":"52789915","name":"Mens Slip On Safety Shoe Burke - Black","sizeVariants":[{"code":"52790010","name":"6","price":"$69","inStock":true},{"code":"52790027","name":"7","price":"$69","inStock":true},{"code":"52790034","name":"8","price":"$69","inStock":false},{"code":"52790041","name":"9","price":"$69","inStock":true},{"code":"52790058","name":"10","price":"$69","inStock":true},{"code":"52790065","name":"11","price":"$69","inStock":true},{"code":"52790072","name":"12","price":"$69","inStock":true}],"media":[{"standard":"http://www.mywebsite.com/medias/static_content/product/images/large/41/21/A814121.jpg","thumbnail":"http://www.mywebsite.com/medias/static_content/product/images/thumb/41/21/A814121.jpg"},{"standard":"http://www.mywebsite.com/medias/static_content/product/images/large/41/27/A814127.jpg","thumbnail":"http://www.mywebsite.com/medias/static_content/product/images/thumb/41/27/A814127.jpg"}],"price":"$69","inStock":true}],"features":[{"name":"Materials and Composition","value":["Upper: Leather","Lining: Synthetic","Sole: Synthetic"]},{"name":"Product Features","value":["Leather upper","Steel toe","Technical cushioned insock to absorb shock when walking"]},{"name":"Care Instructions","value":["Machine Washable"]}],"sizeChartUrl":"http://www.mywebsite.com/size-chart/menshoe","deliveryModes":[{"available":true,"description":"Free for orders over $19. Not available to all stores. Allow 4-10 business days before pickup.","name":"Click + Collect","excludesCountryStore":false},{"available":true,"description":"Free for orders over $75 (excluding large items). Allow 3-10 business days for delivery.","name":"Home Delivery","excludesCountryStore":false},{"available":false,"description":"For apparel only orders.  Not available to all locations. Available for orders placed by 12pm Mon to Fri","name":"Express Delivery","excludesCountryStore":false}],"infoLinks":[{"name":"FAQs","url":"http://www.mywebsite.com/modal/faqs"},{"name":"Payments + Delivery","url":"http://www.mywebsite.com/modal/payment-delivery"},{"name":"Refunds + Returns","url":"http://www.mywebsite.com/modal/refunds-returns"}],"code":"52790027"}'
]%%

{{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxRows = 20}}
{{.data}}
{ "target" : "@Json2" }
{{/data}}
    Name: {{name}}<br>
    productcode: {{baseProductCode}}<br>

    {{.datasource colourVariants type=nested maxRows = 20}}
    {{.data}}
    { "target" : "JsonVar.colourVariants" }
    {{/data}}

        Here is the price: {{Price}}<br>
        Sizes available:
        <ul>

        {{.datasource sizeVariants type=nested maxRows = 20}}
        {{.data}}
        { "target" : "colourVariants.sizeVariants" }
        {{/data}}
            <li>{{code}}: (size {{name}})</li>
        {{/datasource}}

        </ul>

    {{/datasource}}
{{/datasource}}
```

In my environment a test send of this email yields the following HTML output:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
Name: Mens Slip On Safety Shoe Burke - Black<br>
productcode: P52789915<br>
Here is the price: $69<br>
Sizes available:
<ul>
    <li>52790010: (size 6)</li>
    <li>52790027: (size 7)</li>
    <li>52790034: (size 8)</li>
    <li>52790041: (size 9)</li>
    <li>52790058: (size 10)</li>
    <li>52790065: (size 11)</li>
    <li>52790072: (size 12)</li>
</ul>
```